# Can't open Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

After a brand new installation of Anaconda i can't open Jupyter Notebook in a browser. If i try to open it i get the following output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVVTy.png)

pressing f12 while trying to open jupyter notebook yields the following output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOaf1.png)

so it seems that some js files couldn't be loaded..

I have already tried the following:

- start jupyter notebook with a command prompt (also as administrator)
- different browsers (internet explorer, chrome, firefox)
- default jupyter config
- changing between localhost and 127:0.0.1 in the address bar
- reinstalled pyzmq and jupyter
- updated pyzmq

Comment: try these commands:  conda uninstall pyzmq (to removes jupyter related packages!)
conda install pyzmq (to reinstall )
conda install jupyter (to reinstall )

Comment: same error again

Comment: check if this paths are there in the path variable. 
1) C:\ML\installed_tools\anaconda3 
2) C:\ML\installed_tools\anaconda3\Scripts 
3) C:\ML\installed_tools\anaconda3\Library\bin
4)C:\ML\installed_tools\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin

Comment: some times you might just need to update pyzmq: 
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade pyzmq

Comment: all of the above paths are in the path variable and updated pyzmq..still not working..

Comment: You open cmd using "Run as adminstration" or normal click

Comment: i have tried both